# Redirecting a web page from a server I can't control to my personal domain

Tags: website, redirection, web-development

I am trying to redirect my web page provided by my university to my new personal domain.

I don't have access to all the nuts and bolts of the server, but from my ftp login I added a `.htaccess` file.  In that `.htaccess` file, I added the line `Redirect /index.html http://www.mydomain.com`.  However, this just gives me "Forbidden 403" when I try to access my university page now.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try a `Redirect 301 / http://www.new.com`, since right now you are redirecting only the page, `index.html` (though I would expect that to work).  Otherwise, your school domain may limit the use of `.htaccess`, so instead you could do an immediate `meta` refresh in the `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your college's information department. This has to be a regular occurrence (students with websites graduating) and if they are on top of things they will have a regular protocol/method for handling this request. If nothing else, it will keep them from claiming you're up to something illegitimate if a vulnerability scan sees your meta refresh and throws an alert.